# error messages in eclipse IDE when opening .php and .tpl files

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, task-parallel-library

Been using eclipse for a short while. I run `ubuntu 10.10` and have installed `Eclipse web tools platform plug-ins for ecplise` and the `php development tools plug-in`, when I started a `php project` I also installed the `php perspective`, but this doesn't work when I run php files?!

I get this error

> Unsupported content type in editor

So when I edit php files I use the `Java perspective`. This works. I can't say that eclipse impress much with all these weird errors when I install every thing by default and are only doing simple tasks, like editing a php file with a php editor..

I also get this error when I open `.tpl` files (`smarty template engine files`)

> Could not open the editor: The editor
>   class could not be instantiated. This
>   usually indicates a missing no-arg
>   constructor or that the editor's class
>   name was mistyped in plugin.xml.

Thats my main problem.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but I would give Aptana www.aptana.com a try. It's Eclipse based but more focus on Web Development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing the file association,You need go to  preference general > content type > Text and add extension For example , I need *.tpl to be open in HTML editor, than I can do like below.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error namely: `Unsupported content type in editor`

And solved it this way: You need to open it in navigator (`window -> show view -> navigator`) not the php perspective or project view or anything else.

At least this worked for me hope it also helps you!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to your JRE installation.

See those two forum threads:

http://forum.gentleware.com/viewtopic.php?t=4113

http://www.anddev.org/eclipse_fails_to_load_editors_sometimes-t3156.html

Quote:

> Reasons could be manifold.
>
> Most popular: You're running Apollo
>   for Eclipse with JRE version < 1.5.
>   Look for a line saying
>   java.vm.version=xxx in Help->About
>   Eclipse SDK->Configuration Details